# MS Access 2010 - No way to create new database objects (table/query/etc) via shortcut or right click in navigation pane?

Tags: microsoft-access

Minor problem I suppose, but is there no way to create new tables, queries, modules, etc in MS Access 2010 without switching to the "Create" tab?

One would expect to be able to right click in an object group and choose "New...", but is this not the case (or do I possibly have something configured wrong)?

### Update (re: closure votes)

This is a question related to the fundamental UI design in Access 2010 - as pointed out below, it is 2 clicks either way, but *which* two clicks are vastly different.  Right clicking is context sensitive - I don't need to know *where* to click; I click where I am, and actions that are contextually relevant should be displayed.  This is instinctually what I expected as a user of MS products for 15+ years so was extremely surprised to not see it as an option, as I expect other experienced users would - having a definitive answer to this would be useful.

Comment: This may be a fundamental question on the UI of Access, but it's not a programming question, and I don't see how you could get an authoritative answer (if there is one) unless you are within MS itself and worked on that particular UI decision (or lack of thereof). At any rate, it doesn't belong on SO and will probably be moved to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.

However, a right click = one mouse click
Choosing new = one mouse click.

So, at this point in time we are up to 2 clicks. And from the ribbon, we have one click on create, and one click to choose create a table, form etc.

So, we are talking about two mouse clicks in both cases.